# Disk 0 doesn't show when using PowerShell Get-Disk

Tags: windows, powershell, hard-drive, storage

On one machine I'm using, the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-Disk` doesn't show `Disk 0`. But using other commands it will...

```
Get-Disk | Select Number, FriendlyName, HealthStatus, Size

Number FriendlyName    HealthStatus        Size
------ ------------    ------------        ----
     1 Kingston DT2000 Healthy      15502147584
```

```
C:\> Get-Disk -Number 0

Get-Disk : No MSFT_Disk objects found with property 'Number' equal to '0'. 
Verify the value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Disk -Number 0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (0:UInt32) [Get-Disk], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_Number,Get-Disk
```

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Select DeviceId, FriendlyName, HealthStatus, Size

DeviceId FriendlyName                     HealthStatus          Size
-------- ------------                     ------------          ----
1        Kingston DT2000                  Healthy        15502147584
0        KXG50ZNV1T02 NVMe TOSHIBA 1024GB Healthy      1024209543168
```

```
'list disk' | DiskPart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.17763.1911

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: WIN-6S1H8T9U9AT

DISKPART>
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          953 GB  1024 KB   *    *
  Disk 1    Online           14 GB  2048 KB
```

```
Get-Volume | Select DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel, HealthStatus, Size

DriveLetter FileSystemLabel HealthStatus          Size
----------- --------------- ------------          ----
                            Healthy          100663296
C                           Healthy      1023562215424
            Recovery        Healthy          523235328
D           KINGSTON        Healthy        15498014720
```

`Get-Partition` is also acting up...

```
Get-Partition


   DiskPath: \\?\usbstor#disk&ven_kingston&prod_dt2000&rev_...

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                     Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                     ---- ----
1                D           4128768                                14.43 GB IFS
```

Any ideas why `Get-Disk` and `Get-Partition` is missing `Disk 0`?

Edit 1: Added DiskPart output.
Edit 2: Added error message when forcing `Get-Disk` to get Disk 0.

Comment: What happens with diskpart?

Comment: `'list disk' | DiskPart` handles `Disk 0`

Comment: Is disk 0 in diskpart the same disk as your getting with 1 in PowerShell. PowerShell might use a different numbering in which number they start. But that's something powershell internal I would suggest to ask on the github of the powershell team https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: I've updated the question with the `DiskPart` output. And `Disk 1` is the same in both cases.

Comment: Can you try `Get-Disk -Number 0`

Comment: Yep, did that before. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to Disk 0 being a dynamic disk.

The `Get-Disk` cmdlet only shows basic disks and *not* dynamic disks. Quoting the from the [about page for Get-Disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-disk):

> This cmdlet returns physical disk objects like basic disks and partitioned drive partitions. Dynamic disks can span multiple pieces of physical media, so they will not be returned by Get-Disk.

You find dynamic disks by running the following statement in PowerShell:

`Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskPartition -Filter "Type='Logical Disk Manager'"`

The presence of LDM (Logical Disk Manager) information in the output would indicate it is a dynamic disk.

Comment: That is in deed the case. Thx 

Comment: Although your filter doesn't work.

Comment: Strange that MS decided not to return Dynamic Disks using `Get-Disk`, but **will** return Dynamic Disks when using `Get-PhysicalDisk` :)